# ArrayList<Object> sending trought socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, arraylist

i have an ArrayList. I have connected Java Server and Android with a socket. How may i send ArrayList from Android to Java Server?

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private String number;

    public Person(String name, String nr){
        this.name = name;
        number = nr;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;

    }
    public String getNr(){
        return number;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice...

Comment: Yes, i know, but there is no answer to this question

Comment: And i wasted 6 hours, till desided to ask again, and here is a good answer.

Comment: You already got an answer to the question last time, and this time the question isn't even a real question. Where is the error you are getting? What did you try so far? You cannot just expect somebody here to solve the problem for you.

Comment: Sice this is a standard Problem, one could post a link to someone already solved that. It's not a new algorithm which has to be invented for him

Comment: I'm not expecting to solve the problem for me, i just asked for help. And Roberto showed me the right way. Maybe this is a standart problem, but i never faced it before.

Comment: @Lauris01 above a link with hopefully working code

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem for now, but it will help me in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Person is already Serializabe you could use an ObjectOutputStream on top of an byteArrayOutpuStream. And transfer the byte array.
If your server knows the class Person (because it has your jar linked). It can read in the byte Array and call a ObjectInputStream.

Example:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Persons>();
// TODO fill persons.

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bao);
oos.writeObject(persons);
oos.close();

byte[] byteToTransfer = oos.getBytes();
// transfer
```

On server side:

```
byte[] bytesFromSocket = ....;
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesFromSocket);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectOutputStream(bis);
List<Persons> persons = (List<Persons>) ois.readObject(persons);
```

Once you have understood this, look at a more complete code working a bit differently:

[Java sockets - Custom Objects Sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834881/java-sockets-custom-objects-sending?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Make a toString and a fromString method. Or even better, use GSON.

Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects to their JSON representation.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Ah sorry I intermixed that with Geo-JSON

Comment: Np m8 could you vote up. If u want to?

Comment: The communication is between two Java sockets, not Javascript and a Java based server. Why use GSON over Java Serialisation?

Comment: An advantage of JSON is that it is text, and could read from other non java systems, and the messages ar easier debugged, because are human readable. (There also is BSON) binary JSON, which need less bytes. You coudl save money, and the priject is faster when having easy to debug human readable messages. It much depens on the project.

Comment: What exactly would you debug with human readable messages that you can't debug with the debugger? Unless you're going to look at the actual packets being send between the sockets, there will always be a java objects around for you to introspect.